# get elements by class name with query from another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I want something like this

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.innerHTML = data;
 var List=newDiv.$(".myclass h4");
    console.log($(List[0]).html());
```

but it doesnot work.

Comment: Did you mean `$(List).html()` instead of `$(List[0]).html()`? What “first element” are you trying to access? What precisely does “doesn’t work” mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you make that `newDiv` a jQuery object, and then use `find()`, you can get the other element within it.

```
$(newDiv).find(".myclass h4");
```

Stack snippet

```js
var data = "<div class='myclass'><h4>hello</h4></div>"
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = data;
var List = $(newDiv).find(".myclass h4");
console.log( $(List).html() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is passing as the second parameter the created element as the parent/source DOM element to find elements from it.

```
$(".myclass h4", newDiv);  <--- This call returns a jQuery object.
                 ^
                 |
                 +--- Parent/Source element
```

```js
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="myclass"><h4>Ele from Stack</h4></div>';

var list = $(".myclass h4", newDiv);
console.log(list.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```